# Setting a value with curly brackets in XmlConfig with WIX xslt

Tags: wix, xslt-2.0

i am trying to set a value in WIX XmlConfig which contains curly brackets

I want to set a value like this "IndexServer__%property{name}.zip"

```
<util:XmlFile 
    Id="AppConfigLocalFileDebugLogPath"
    Action="setValue"
    Permanent="yes" 
    ElementPath="//configuration/log4net/appender[\[]@name='LocalFileDebugLog'[\]]/file/@value"
    Value="[LOGFILEROOTPATH]\IndexServer\Debug\IndexServer_DEBUG__%property[\{]index-name[\}].log"
    File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Index.Webservice.exe.config"                   
    SelectionLanguage="XPath"
    Sequence="1"
/>
```

I thought it could work with [{] and [}] because [[] and []] works fine but it doesnt. I get following error from HEAT"HEAT5055: Error applying transform xxxxx to harvested Wix: unexpected token ']' in expression"

(or something like that, the original error message is in german ;-) )

If i simply try:

```
<util:XmlFile 
     Id="AppConfigLocalFileDebugLogPath"
     Action="setValue"
     Permanent="yes" 
     ElementPath="//configuration/log4net/appender[\[]@name='LocalFileDebugLog'[\]]/file/@value"
     Value="[LOGFILEROOTPATH]\IndexServer\Debug\IndexServer_DEBUG__%property{index-name}.log"
     File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Index.Webservice.exe.config"                   
     SelectionLanguage="XPath"
     Sequence="1"
 />
```

This results in a string like "E:\LogFiles\WSIndexServer\WSIndexServer__%property.log" as you can see the string "{index-name}" gets lost ;-(

Could you help me here? I need the part "{index-name}" including the curly brackets in the string.

Thanks a lot

Chris

Answer (score 1):

As the question is tagged as XSLT and as you say that with `Value="[LOGFILEROOTPATH]\IndexServer\Debug\IndexServer_DEBUG__%property{index-name}.log"` the `{index-name}` is lost I suppose that value is evaluated in XSLT and you need to double the `{}` to avoid being treated as an attribute value template, so try `Value="[LOGFILEROOTPATH]\IndexServer\Debug\IndexServer_DEBUG__%property{{index-name}}.log"`.

Comment: Hey Martin thanks a lot this works - Its so simple ;-)

Comment: @chris079, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work on how to indicate that your problem is solved.